# mkdir in kaniko fails with can't create directory - File exists

Tags: docker, jenkins, mkdir, kaniko

I'm trying to execute the following Dockerfile with [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) on a Jenkins node

```
FROM docker.mycompany.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine

COPY app.jar app.jar

RUN mkdir /some-directory
```

But I'm getting the error

```
mkdir: can't create directory '/some-directory': File exists
```

I've checked the base image (`adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine`) and I can see that `/some-directory` does not exist so I'm not sure why kaniko is telling me the directory already exists.

I'm using the following Kaniko command

```
/kaniko/executor /
  --context dir://myproject/src/main/docker /
  --dockerfile myproject/src/main/docker/Dockerfile /
  --destination docker-staging.docker.mycompany.io/foo/myproject:111.222.333 /
  --registry-certificate docker-staging.docker.mycompany.io=/etc/ssl/certs/mycompany.crt /
  --verbosity=debug /
  --cache=true
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Kaniko command actually succeeded the first time on a clean Jenkins node, it was only second / subsequent executions on the same Jenkins node where the mkdir would fail so it seems I had a dirty kaniko filesystem when the error occurs.

I solved this by adding the `--cleanup` and `--cache=false` flags to the Kaniko command.

I believe that in newer versions of Kaniko I could use the [`--cache-run-layers=false`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/main/README.md#flag---cache-run-layers) flag but I'm using an older version of Kaniko which does not have this option